# Asking questions re: plugin development critiquing

Tags: discussion

Is it considered off-topic in WP.se to post plugins we've created (or are creating) and ask for critiques, feature recommendations, likelihood of demand, etc.? I'm talking about plugins that haven't yet been submitted to wordpress.org.

If not off-topic, would a link to a plugin.zip be preferable to posting what could be a bunch of files, sub-directories, etc.

Also, along the same vein, is it off-topic to make announcements of new plugins we've created that are already accepted by wordpress.org?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While code review was not explicitly declared on or off topic ( [Code Review on WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281/code-review-on-wordpress-answers) ) de-facto it had never gained traction and it just doesn't seem the right format for the site (localized, no "right" answer, etc).

Release announcements of such kind are definitely not in scope. QA, not forum.

Comment: Thanks, Rarst. I've read through that link, and will check out codereview.se.

Answer (score 1):

I think such questions fall somewhere in both **not constructive** and **not a real question**:

Not constructive:

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Not a real question:

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

Such a question is *not constructive*, because it will lead to debate/opinion and extended discussion.

Such a question is *not a real question* because it is too open-ended/overly broad, and does not constitute a specific, focused question that will lead to a specific, focused answer.

Comment: Thanks for the input, Chip. Per the link from Rarst, I'm thinking to post to CodeReview.se and see how that fares.